# Check two table value in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

**Customer :**

```
id | custname | phone
---------------------
1  | abc      | 123
2  | xyz      | 456
3  | qwe      | 786
4  | asd      | 1234
```

**Register   :**

```
id | regname  | status  |Desc
-----------------------------------
1  | abc      | 1       | text here
2  | cvw      | 0       | text here
3  | fgr      | 1       | text here
4  | asd      | 0       | text here
```

*cust matches in regname*  : `abc and asd`

Then I want out put matches `custnname` for *customer* and *register* table details.

```
id | custname | status  |Desc
-----------------------------------
1  | abc      | 1       | text here
2  | asd      | 0       | text here
```

How to do it with PHP MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple `JOIN` between the 2 tables
so what you want is:

```
SELECT customer.id,customer.custname,register.status,register.desc
FROM customer
JOIN register ON register.regname = customer.custname
```

since we use `JOIN` it acts as an `inner join` and will only return values that match it

for more on mysql join look here:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this query with join:

```
"SELECT customer.custname,register.status,register.Desc 
 FROM customer 
 JOIN register ON register.regname = customer.custname"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to keep all values that are inside `customers` and `registers`:

```
select c.id, c.custname, r.status, r.Desc
from customers c
inner join register r on r.regname = c.custname
```

Will outputs:

```
id | custname | status  |Desc
-----------------------------------
1  | abc      | 1       | text here
4  | asd      | 0       | text here
```

NB: not sure about which ID you want. You could use `c.id` or `r.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
SELECT c.id as ID,c.custname as Customer Name,r.status as Status,r.desc as Description
FROM customer as c
INNER JOIN register as r
ON r.regname = c.custname
```